# Database schema: Multiple tables vs id lookup

Tags: database-design

I am building a subscription feature where users can sign up for different mailing lists according to a single category (ie, "Books").

In designing my tables in MySQL, I've come across two options:

**Option 1**

```
/* Table 1 */
Books
    Email

/* Table 2 */
Magazines
    Email
```

Each user can subscribe to more than one list.

**Option 2**

```
/* Table 1 */
All Categories
    Email
    Category_ID

/* Table 2 */
Category_ID
    Category
```

I'm basically cross-referencing a category ID from a master table of all emails. In that table, emails could repeat since a user could subscribe to more than one category. I figure I'd want to give each category an ID instead of referencing an actual string in the database although I'm not experienced in database schema design.

Which would you go for? Is it faster to cross-reference a category ID or just break each category into its own table? (assuming i'm emails a long list to notify users when a new comment comes in on each category).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option is a more normalized form, as it doesn't replicate data (e-mails) in multiple tables. I'd go one step further with your second option and create a user table (because you'll undoubtedly need to store more than just an e-mail in the future) and store the user's UserID in your first table, rather than the e-mail address. This will ensure that when a user needs to update their e-mail address, you don't need to update multiple tables (as in option #1) or multiple records in a single table (option #2). Denormalization (option #1) is ok when you require your queries to be super quick (no joins), but has many drawbacks when it comes to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations. In your case I'd choose a modified option 2 for the reasons described above.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Should I be concerned about speed if I'm sending out a notification on a comment submit to everyone in the appropriate list?

Comment: I'd say no. Joins can get nasty, but not until you have tons of rows in both your tables, and indexes solve this. Also, I'm assuming the time it takes to send out notifications will trump the time it takes mySQL to handle your query, so the speed of the query won't matter much. You can verify this by putting a timer on your mySQL call, and a timer on the code that sends out a single notification, comparing results.